# How should I secure my site for logins?

Tags: tls, authentication

I am making my very first site, and I need a way, to secure it.

Users must be able to post stuff on my site, but I want to prevent throttling my site or using bots to break it. I thought of making sign up/in system, but it's vulnerable to all kinds of attacks without SSL certificate, and it would cause users big trouble.

I just can't afford SSL certificate, I generally have $0 to spend to get one.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: There is little you can do without SSL. Get a free cert from https://www.startssl.com/ and then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: @OverCoder once you get your SSL certificate installed on your webserver, use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check your configuration for potential flaws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little you can do without SSL. Get a free cert from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/) and then come back with more specific questions.